# Parsing json array without keys in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I can parse this json, stored in a string called json.

```
{
 "contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
    }
 ]
}
```

Using this code in Android:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray ob = object.getJSONArray("contacts");
```

The thing is that I want to parse the same JSON array but without the key or name "contacts", something like this:

```
{
 [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
    }
 ]
}
```

The method `getJSONArray()` requires the name of the array, but in this case it does not have one. Is it possible to parse this or is the Json syntax not right?

Comment: The JSON is invalid. You should get your money back for it. http://json.org/object.gif

Comment: Why are you manually parsing the JSON? Use an auto mapper like GSON http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

Comment: or... use a proper json parser like JACKSON

Answer (score 0):

`getJSONArray` requires a name because, as per [the JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627):

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.

As such, there's no API to get the array (or any other type) without a name, because that wouldn't make any sense. Your object as defined in your question has no name, only a value, so it is invalid.

If you wish to only pass down the array, remove the curly brackets - your JSON should look like this:

```
 [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com"
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com"
    }
 ]
```

There's no reason to use jackson. And you can parse the above String like so:

```
JSONArray contactArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

Comment: that json is still invalid, it has trailing commas after email

Answer (score 0):

You can Easily do it using gson library.Here is the code sample:
You need two Entity Class , One is Holder Class and another is Entity Class.
The Entity Class will like this:

```
 public class ResponseEntity {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String email;
}


public class ResponseRoot{
    @SerializedName("contacts")
    public List<ResponseEntity> entities=null;

public ResponseRoot(){
    entities=new ArrayList<ResponseEntity>();
}
}
```

Now Convert this json Array using GSON library.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();    
ResponseRoot entities = (ResponseRoot)gson.fromJson(yourResponseAsString.toString(),
      ResponseRoot.class);
```

Now `entities contains ResponseEntity elements. Using iteration you can get all enitiies

Thanks`

Answer (score -1):

your json should resemble this:-

```
[
   {
      "id":"c200",
      "name":"Ravi Tamada",
      "email":"ravi@gmail.com"
   },
   {
      "id":"c201",
      "name":"Johnny Depp",
      "email":"johnny_depp@gmail.com"
   }
]
```

the jackson json libraries can cope with json without key names

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {

        // read json file data to String
        byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("contacts.json"));

        // create ObjectMapper instance
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // convert json string to object
        final Holder holder = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Holder.class);

        for (final Contact contact : holder.getContacts()) {
            System.out.println("id = " + contact.getId());
            System.out.println("name = " + contact.getName());
            System.out.println("email = " + contact.getEmail());
        }
    }
}


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

public class Holder {

    private final Contact[] contacts;

    @JsonCreator
    public Holder(final Contact[] contacts) {
        super();
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public Contact[] getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

}


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Contact {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final String email;

    @JsonCreator
    public Contact(@JsonProperty("id") final String id, @JsonProperty("name") final String name, @JsonProperty("email") final String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

}
```

the content of `contacts.json` is

```
[
   {
      "id":"c200",
      "name":"Ravi Tamada",
      "email":"ravi@gmail.com"
   },
   {
      "id":"c201",
      "name":"Johnny Depp",
      "email":"johnny_depp@gmail.com"
   }
]
```

Comment: whats wrong with this solution? and once again thanks to SO for a downvote with no explanation!

Comment: issue #1: "the jackson json libraries can cope with json without key names" - this is wrong. the jackson json libraries can not (and should not) cope with illegal json schema. key names are required within objects. to say that jackson can magically handle this is very misleading.

Comment: issue #2: you do not actually explain what is going wrong with what he is doing. you are simply saying "oh use this library, and don't even worry about how any of this stuff works." A good answer should explain what exactly is going wrong, and options to directly address it.

Comment: my code uses jackson which parses this json fine, where is the misleading part?

Comment: the questions asked are "Is it possible to parse this or is the Json syntax not right?" both of which i answered

Comment: jackson does not parse *his* json fine, as you imply it does with your "jackson can cope" line.

Comment: Yes, and you should improve your answer to explain why it isn't json, and why adding a 200kB+ library (Jackson) is a better solution. you haven't done either of those things.